# Honda PS125i 2008, I have a spark, fuel, pressure but still doesn't want to run

Tags: engine, honda, electrical, motorcycle

I'm working on a Honda PES125i from 2008, in November he came to me and said the bike didn't want to run anymore. He said that first the bike started to stall when he was standing at red lights and then it just didn't want to do it at all anymore.
I did a quick maintenance, changed the oil, new airfilter, iridium sparkplug, etc.

It started again properly only I noticed when the engine started to heat, the idling went down and it would stall.
I changed the idling rpm on the throttle body and it was fine for a while.

Then he said that the same thing happened again, and the bike didn't want to start at all anymore.

I did the following things:

- I fully recharged the battery, and tried to start it. to no avail.
- I removed the spark plug and noticed it was proper wet.
- I checked for the resistance of the ignition coil and have on he primary coil 2.7 Ohm and on the secondary 8.3K Ohm the cap on the spark plug looks in decent nick and has a resistance of 5K Ohm.
- With the spark plug unscrewed and leaning against the opening I started the bike and saw a nice spark and even notice that the fuel being injected was combusting.

Can anyone give me some tips of what to check next and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!